# dynamically display divs with same class on the left and the next on the right and so on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to find a way to display divs with the same class on the left and right and so on....

something similar to the facebook chat... so, the first one is on the left and the second one is on the right and the third one is on the left and the fourth one is on the right and so on....

THE DIVS ARE GENRATED VIA PHP FROM THE MYSQL DATABASE.

is this possible using CSS or do i need to use jquery/javascript?

This is the code that I have so far:

```
<div style="width:100%;" ><img style="float:left;" src="images/icon.png" width="80" height="80"/><div style="float:left;"><p class="messageme">Hello My friend.. </p>


</div>
```

CSS:

```
.messageme{
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    padding:5px;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#999;
    background-color:#FFF;
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    clear:both;
    max-width:550px;
    text-align:left;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px 0px #CCC;
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 11px 0px #CCC;
box-shadow:         0px 0px 11px 0px #CCC;

float:left;

margin-left:15px;

}
```

any advise would be appreciated.

Thanks

okay, now I get the amount of divs using this code:

```
<script>
var nb = $('.messageme').length;
alert(nb);
</script>
```

I need to know how I can get even and odd numbers.. I use the folowing code but I get no alerts at all:

```
<script>
var nb = $('.messageme').length;

function isEven(nb) {
    if (nb%2 == 0)
        alert('even');
    else
        alert('odd');
}
</script>
```

Comment: If you put them inside separate parent `<div>`s and give them a `width` and `float:left;` on them, you won't have to change the `class`.

Comment: @PHPglue, sorry I'm not sure what you mean! the float:left; will float all of them on the left.. but i need to float one on the left the next on the right etc etc...

Comment: So you can't control the PHP?

Answer (score 2):

### CSS solution for IE9+ and all major browsers

Ever heard of CSS `:nth-child(odd)` or `:nth-child(even)`?

**HTML**

```
<div id="messages">
    <p>Hello My friend.. </p>
    <p>Hey dude!</p>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#messages p{
    float:left;
}

#messages p:nth-child(even){
    float:right;
}
```

#### JS Fiddle demo

### Looking for an IE8-proof solution?

Here is a way to do it in javascript:

```
var messages = document.getElementById('messages').getElementsByTagName('p');

for(var i=1, l=messages.length; i<l; i=i+2){
    messages[i].style.styleFloat = 'right'; // IE
    messages[i].style.cssFloat = 'right'; // others
}
```

#### JS Fiddle demo

Comment: No it's not. Unless he is doing this for a company who has not updated their systems, he is most certainly not going to need to support IE8. It works with IE9+ and all major browsers.

Comment: I usually develop for the worst case scenario, even if it means using a little more code.. But you're right, for small companies it doesn't really matter

Comment: @OryanM That's a good thing to worry about. I must admit I never consider my clients using IE under version 9, I'm hoping it will _force_ people into updating if that's not the case.

Comment: I did use :nth-child(odd) before but this seems to only work with child <p> if I'm not wrong!! because it has no affect on my code as its shown in my question!

Comment: @shell Would [this javascript code](http://jsfiddle.net/ngsqaw0n/4/) fit your needs?

Comment: @blex, no not really as its using <p></p> as child within div messages! my code structure is totally different than what you have provided in your example. Thanks anyway and i appreciate your help.

Comment: I wouldn't bother supporting IE 8, those people are probably using Windows XP which isn't even supported by Microsoft anymore unless you work at a company that is paying through the nose for extended support. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/end-support-help

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is everytime I generate a div I'd check the current number of divs in the container, if it's odd I'll add float left, and if it's even float right.

Comment: good idea.. do you do the odd/even check using javascript or PHP?

Comment: You don't call the function anywhere, you declare it but you need to call it somewhere like you  call any function (isEven(nb))

Answer (score 0):

Got it sorted.

i use this jquery code to get odd/even numbers and then edit the float accordingly...

```
<script>
function checkEven(nb){
     return (nb%2 == 0);
}

var nb = $('.messageme').length;

if(checkEven(nb)){
    alert("Number is even");
} else {
    alert("Number is odd");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a JavaScript even and odd solution:

```
function everyOtherFloat(insideNode, startAtChild, floatRight){
  var nds = insideNode.getElementsByTagName('*'), l = 'left', r = 'right';
  var s = startAtChild ? startAtChild : 0;
  if(floatRight){
    l = 'right'; r = 'left';
  }
  for(var i=s,n=s+1,c=nds.length; i<c; i+=2,n+=2){
    var ln = nds[i].style, rn = nds[n].style;
    ln.cssFloat = ln.styleFloat = l; rn.cssFloat = rn.styleFloat = r;
  }
}
```

Let's make life easy:

```
var doc = document;
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
// floating left starting with the first Node in id='messages' - Node 0
everyOtherFloat(E('messages'));

// floating left starting at Node 1 - if you need to skip top Node
everyOtherFloat(E('messages'), 1);

// floating right first starting at Node 0 - third argument can be anything truthy
everyOtherFloat(E('messages'), 0, 1);
```

I would actually use a PHP HTML creating solution if you're getting the information right when the page loads. If you're getting the information when an Event occurs, I would use AJAX.